# Examples of application of detour matrices in physics?

Tags: mathematical-physics, computational-physics, linear-algebra, graph-theory

Are there any good examples of application of [detour matrices](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DetourMatrix.html) in physics?

Comment: What is a "good" example and what is a "not good" example?

Comment: When in doubt of that, recommend any.   Otherwise, any example is a good one in the absence of any examples.

Comment: I know someone who investigated graph theory methods for stellar nucleosynthesis as part of his PhD thesis, but I'm not sure if he ever went so far as making detour matrices there.

Comment: Would you care to give the author/title of the thesis.  If it's machine readable, a search of "detour matrices/matrix" might find something interesting?

Comment: I searched it and found no "detour" inside it, but it's [here if you want it](http://tigerprints.clemson.edu/all_dissertations/506/).